# Working with Smarty and PHP variables

Tags: php, smarty

Here is the scenario.

I have text in the DB that looks like this:

```
blah blah blah blah blah {$name} {$index}
```

As you may see it contains two Smarty variables `{$name}`  and `{$index}`

Now I need to assign the values to the variables with Smarty. For those who do not know Smarty, values can be easily assigned this way:

```
$smarty->assign('name_of_the_variable', $variable);
```

The problem is that this text is coming from the DB, and I do not know which variables will be in the text, so I am trying to abstract the code doing the following:

```
    function getPageContent($page) {

        $smarty = new Smarty(); // initializing Smarty

    //selecting the content and saving it into the $content variable
        $q='SELECT * FROM pages_blocks WHERE Page="'.$page.'"';
         $r=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
              $content = $row['Content'];
               }

//defining variables
        $name = "NAME";
        $index = "INDEX";

    //getting all the variables inside brackets {}
               preg_match_all('/{(.+)}/U', $content, $matches);


    //abstracting the code assigning values to the variables found   
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
         $foo = str_replace('$', '', $match); //removing the $ to give a name to smarty
          $smarty->assign(''.$foo.'', $match); //final assignation of name and its variable
         }
           $smarty->display('string:'.$content); //displaying the final content
        }
```

The problem is that the final content looks like:

```
blah blah blah blah blah $name $index
```

Instead of

```
blah blah blah blah blah NAME INDEX
```

Something is wrong. Smarty is printing the variables as they are instead of running them before as normal.

Please help me.

Comment: I tried also to eval($match) but with no luck at all.

Comment: don't use smarty. PHP is already a powerful template engine

Comment: Good advise. But it's not helping me at all at the moment. I am using Smarty and I need a solution using it...

Comment: I know that's why i just made a comment

Answer (score 3):

Replace this:

```
$smarty->assign(''.$foo.'', $match);
```

With this:

```
$smarty->assign(''.$foo.'', ${$foo});
```

Comment: Why? What was the problem? I am curious

Comment: `eval` isn't the right way to load a variable based off another variable name. `${...}` is the way, where "..." is like a string with interpolation, so you can put other variables in there.

Comment: For example, consider the code: `$a = '1';` `$b = 'a';` `echo ${$b};` Will echo "1".

Comment: ok but it's not working with arrays, variables like $lang['city'] does not work..can you help me?

Comment: For something like that, you'll have to divide the string into components, `lang` and `city` (use a regexp or however you want to do it). So say you have them separated into variables called $key (== 'lang') and $ind (== 'city'). Then you can do ${$key}[$ind].

Answer (score 0):

You're using regexp `{(.+)}`, `.+` will "eat" everything it sees, so it'll match: `$name} {$index`.

You should use greedy killer: `''/\\{(.+?)\\}/U''`

Comment: @yes123 any particular reason? I found it as good practice mostly in combination with characters and numbers for case that they get special meaning in future, such as `\d` may be interpreted as `DEL` character or so.